# Construct a column based on Values in two Other column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Hope somebody can help me.  I need some mCODE for Power BI to help construct a column based on two other columns in a data table. People were asked about eating Peas.  They answered in different ways, some answers were text strings without spaces.  I have the data in a table which details Names and the Answer returned by that name.  I would like mCODE to constuct a column that gives an Answer "YES" if anyone of the same name in the table gives an answer that contains PEAS in the answer string, regardless of string case or string spacing. The mCODE should construct a column called "Yes or No". The code should not rely on rows being listed in name or answer order. I give a sample of my massive data table below.  One Fred answered "I like Peas" so all FREDS get assigned "YES".  No one called Anne Mentioned PEAS so all Annes Get assigned "No". George's Answer had no spaces but contained Peas so All Georges would get assigned Yes. Hope this Makes sense and Somebody can code this.
Would Take a Dax Code Solution, but would prefer mCODE
Thanks in Advance rockingmark

[Table showing my data is in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozMWK.png.)

New to mCODE so Havent tried anything.  DIdnt know how to summarise the problem for google or Bing to return an answer

Tried to use horseyride's power query code below but couldn't get it into power BI.  Adapted the code to read my spread sheet into power BI but the code produces an error in the constructed column at the #grouped rows line

[Attempt at adding it to PowerBI Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33zRS.png)

Error Shown in 3rd Column
[Error Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrkzY.png)

Error Expanded to show error below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7ZbO.png)

Comment: Please post text as text, not images.  No one wants to retype all that to help you.  Not having tried anything yourself is usually the 2nd reason people won't want to help. All that said, a sample answer below.

Comment: Sorry, get your point and did try to add as text but the columns didnt line up properly.  It just pasted as a continuous string.  They dont make it easy to cut and past a table in

Comment: Someone would have to type or paste in all the sample data to try and solve your issue. Why should it be the person trying to help you?

Comment: Thanks, Updated my question with corrected and an additional image. Hopefully this helps. the link Attempt at adding it to PowerBI Query" shows the code I used.  I adapted the source so that POwer BI picks up my table

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

One way in powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Name"}, {
    {"data", each _, type table },
    {"Peas Mentioned", each if List.AnyTrue(List.Transform(_[ANSWER], each Text.Contains(_,"peas",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) then "YES" else "NO"}
}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"ANSWER"}, {"ANSWER"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Horseyride could not get it working in Power BI, see addition to comments in my original question.  Hopefully you can help further.  I am trying to read the source data sheet into Power BI, then construct the 3rd column in the Power BI query editor.

Comment: You didn't paste in the entire code you used, so we have no way of knowing what you did.  You didnt click on the error and tell us what is says, so we have no way to know what the error is.

Comment: You updated question a bit, but didn't show what your input data looks like. Based on the #"Changed Type" step in your code (which, again, was pasted as an image instead of text. Why??) you are starting with just two columns named Column1 and Column2. How then are you grouping and trying to expand a column named Answer ? My code works as provided based on your initial question, so at this point we part ways